# Database.rollback() Method Not Working In Different Transaction?

Tags: apex, future, transaction, savepoint

I have created a very simple scenario where I'm creating a savepoint and trying to rolling back in future method.
The behaviour is little confusing - I tried searching it over the net but I didn't find any post helping me:
What I observed:

- Account record created in the first transaction wasn't deleted when I tried Database.rollback method was executed in Future method - But the rollback did happen. I could see the Limits.getDmlStatements() value increased

Shouldn't the rollback method execution undo the creation of account record?

Also, is there any way to successfully achieve this - Create a savepoint in one transaction and rollback EVERYTHING from another transaction which was started by this first transaction?

Following is the snippet:

```
Public Class SynchronousClass{
    Static SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
    Id recId;
    public void createAccount(){
        Try{
            System.debug('Created Save Point in Synchronous class --> DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements()); //Gives me 1
            Account acc = new Account(Name = 'testAccount12kjlk3');
            Insert acc;
            recId = acc.Id;
        }Catch(Exception e){
            System.debug(e);
        }

        futureMethod(recId);

        System.debug(recId);
        System.debug('Synchronous class End --> DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements()); //Gives me 2

    }

    @future
    Public static void futureMethod(Id recId){
        If(recId != null){
            System.debug('Future before rollback --> DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements()); //Gives me 1
            Database.rollBack(sp);
            System.debug('Future after rollback --> DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements()); //Gives me 2
        }Else System.debug('Record creation failure and Future DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this won't work. Savepoints and rollbacks are scoped inside a single transaction. Once the transaction completes, work is committed to the database. While you can *delete* committed records from another transaction, you can't roll it back.

Here:

```
Static SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();

// ...

@future
Public static void futureMethod(Id recId){
    If(recId != null){
        System.debug('Future before rollback --> DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements()); //Gives me 1
        Database.rollBack(sp);
        System.debug('Future after rollback --> DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements()); //Gives me 2
    }Else System.debug('Record creation failure and Future DML Limits: '+Limits.getDmlStatements());
}
```

In point of fact `sp` represents a *different* `Savepoint` in your future method. Static variables *also* do not live across transactions (no variables do, unless you're using a Stateful batch class or a Queueable with instance variables). Your `static` variable's initializer is called once in the initial synchronous transaction, and then a second time in the future transaction. That's why `Database.rollback()` doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`. It's simply rolling back nothing at all. The setting of the savepoint is the one DML operation you start with.

> Also, is there any way to successfully achieve this - Create a savepoint in one transaction and rollback EVERYTHING from another transaction which was started by this first transaction?

No, this is impossible. Since `System.Savepoint` isn't serializable, you can't actually pass it to any type of Asynchronous Apex in the first place.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks David - This also cleared another doubt I had - Why future method was even showing one dml operation.

Answer (score 2):

`Database.rollback` works when everything is happening in a single transaction.

The `future` method initiates a different transaction and cannot be rollbacked. Here after synchronous method commits the records in the database then async `future` method will be initiated.

If you really want to make both of the operations in a single transaction then don't use `future` method.